# Remoção de outilers automatizada

Tags: r, loop

Preciso remover outliers de um banco de dados, de maneira "manual", eu usaria o seguinte comando:

```
a=X
Q1<-quantile(X,0.25)
Q3<-quantile(X,0.75)
IQR<-Q3-Q1
lim_inf=Q1-1.5*IQR
lim_sup=Q3+1.5*IQR
a>lim_sup
a<lim_inf
out=(a>lim_sup)|(a<lim_inf)
a[out]=NA
X=a
```

aqui o comando genérico que eu uso, X é a variável pra remover

Porém esse comando eu preciso sempre alterar a variável X toda hora. Eu gostaria de saber se há como fazer a remoção de maneira mais rápida, algum loop ou algum pacote que remova de todas as colunas que eu ter em um data.frame e troque por NA

Comment: Acabei de achar a fonte da função que tinha postado como resposta graças ao usuário @RuiBarradas. Deletei a resposta, não acho que faz sentido ter outra resposta igual, mesmo citando a fonte, no SO só porque é em outra língua. Segue o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787332/how-to-remove-outliers-from-a-dataset/4788102#4788102) para pergunta muito semelhante no SO En. Vou postar outra resposta com outra forma que fiz.

Answer (score 0):

Graças ao usuário @RuiBarradas que achou a fonte da função que usei 2 anos atrás, você tem no link no comentário eu fiz varias formas de fazer o que deseja (no SO En). Mas no final das contas olhando o script que fiz dois anos atrás eu retirei os outliers utilizando funções do base mesmo, fazendo dessa forma:

```
x_com<- rnorm(100)
boxplot(x)

x_sem<- x[!x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out]
boxplot(x)
```

Espero ter contribuído com mais uma resposta para fazer a mesma coisa rsrs. Se precisar de velocidade faça o benchmarking dessa e das outras na pergunta do SO En e escolha a melhor que se adequa.